# Can I use a field as the 'unit' in TIMESTAMPDIFF?

Tags: mysql

This is a followup to a [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6299090/362520), but I think warrants its own question:

Can I use a field as the 'unit' parameter in `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`?

For example, here's a snippet:

```
SELECT foo FROM table t LEFT JOIN frequencies f USING (frequency_id)
WHERE MOD(TIMESTAMPDIFF(f.frequency_code, t.date, NOW()), t.frequency_num) = 0
```

This gets a syntax error when I run it. Now, if I replace `f.frequency_code` with an actual word - `MINUTE`, `DAY`, etc. - it works. But those are exactly the words currently contained in `f.frequency_code`.

Is it simply not doable to be able to use a table field in that location?

Comment: Without having looked into the MySQL source to see what's truly acceptable, I'm going to guess no - if you get a syntax error, then obviously mysql isn't expecting to get a fieldname in that place. One possible alternative is to try a subquery which returns the interval name, but I doubt that'd work either. Most likely MySQL's parser is expecting to find a literal interval name, and only that literal interval name.

Comment: You could always work with a nested `IF` construction but that would produce terrible code. Interested to see whether anything comes up - although it's possible it's not possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TIMESTAMPDIFF()` does not support dynamic units like that.

Since you're working with a known set of units, you could use a `CASE` statement to achieve this.

Starting with your example query, something like this would probably work:

```
SELECT foo 
FROM table t 
LEFT JOIN frequencies f USING (frequency_id)
WHERE MOD(
(CASE 
  WHEN f.frequency_code = 'MICROSECOND' THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MICROSECOND, t.date, NOW())
  WHEN f.frequency_code = 'SECOND' THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, t.date, NOW())
  WHEN f.frequency_code = 'MINUTE' THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, t.date, NOW())
  WHEN f.frequency_code = 'HOUR' THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, t.date, NOW())
  WHEN f.frequency_code = 'DAY' THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, t.date, NOW())
  WHEN f.frequency_code = 'WEEK' THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(WEEK, t.date, NOW())
  WHEN f.frequency_code = 'MONTH' THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, t.date, NOW())
  WHEN f.frequency_code = 'QUARTER' THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(QUARTER, t.date, NOW())
  WHEN f.frequency_code = 'YEAR' THEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, t.date, NOW())
  END)
, t.frequency_num) = 0
```

Comment: While it might look like ugly code, this is the method I went with. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not 100%, but you might manage to work around the issue by [creating a function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html) that prepares and executes [dynamic sql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Comment: Trying but it doesn't seem to want to take. Good idea, though.